# Azure Notifications hub format tags payload REST API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, azure, azure-notificationhub

I have an ordinary C# MVC website that is connected to a database were I'm storing my phone apps Push IDs.

I take these push IDs and want to send a push to it.
I can do this manually with the send test push function on Microsoft Azure website by inserting the value into the tag field there.

But now I want to do it with the REST API from my website.

I followed this for the .NET example

https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples

The payload for Android looks like this:

```
{\"data\":{\"message\":\"" + message + "\"}}
```

I tried adding the tags to the payload by doing this:

```
{\"data\":{\"message\":\"" + message + "\"}, \"tags\":{\"DeviceToken\":\"the push ID here\"}}
```

But it didn't work. The push got sent to everyone.

How do you use or format the tags in the REST API?

**Solution:**

```
headers.Add("ServiceBusNotification-Tags", recipient);
```

recipient in my case is the installationID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I checked the REST API [Send a GCM Native Notification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223273.aspx) and followed [azure-notificationhubs-samples](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/blob/master/dotnet/SendRestExample/SendRestExample/Program.cs) to test this issue. In order to add tags to your payload, you could specify `ServiceBusNotification-Tags` header. I sent a GCM native notification to a set of tags (game, news), you could refer to it:

[image]

Additionally, you could leverage [Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/) for sending push notifications. For more details, you could refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-backend-windows-dotnet-wns-notification).

Comment: Got it to work for iOS pushes but not Android. I believe the issue might be that I'm not saving the Android tag properly though.